Resolving DNS against an AWS Inbound Endpoint Resolver
Question
Can you send a DNS query to an AWS inbound endpoint resolver asking to lookup a record in a private zone for which it has a resolver rule (e.g. by using a standard DNS client such as nslookup / resolve-dnsname`); or do these handle resolutions in a different way (e.g. so you can only query them from specific solutions which support some alternate DNS protocol) meaning you have to query via (for example) an AD Domain Controller with a conditional forwarder.
Context
We have a Route53 Inbound Endpoint Resolver configured in our AWS Transit Gateway account, with transmission protocol set as Do53.
This resolver has a resolver rule to cover requests to our awscloud.private domain; with each of our AWS accounts having their own <myAccountFriendlyName>.awscloud.private (e.g. production.awscloud.private) private zones.
Our ("on prem" / Azure hosted) Active Directory DNS is configured with a Conditional Forwarder for the awscloud.private zone, with the resolver IPs targetting our inbound endpoint resolver.  This all works as expected; i.e. on my computer I type resolve-dnsname example.production.awscloud.private -server $myDomainController and get back the IP associated with that record from the relevnt AWS private zone.
However, whilst investigating a recent glitch with DNS resolution I found that if I ran resolve-dnsname example.production.awscloud.private -server $myAwsResolverIp it failed to resolve*; even if I ran that command from the existing domain controller (i.e. so coming from the same client IP).  The DC continues to correctly resolve even newly added records (so it's contacting AWS / isn't relying on cached values), but when I try to run a query in PowerShell (or using nslookup in cmd) from the DC instead of querying the DC itself and relying on the conditional forwarder, things time out.
 * By "failed to resolve": specifically it timed out: i.e. This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
This implies that the conditional forwarder isn't doing a normal dns lookup; or at least, it's doing something different to what nslookup/resolve-dnsname do... I'm trying to understand what that is; as to my understanding I should be able to perform a normal DNS lookup against this endpoint, and so long as it's for a domain managed there, I'm not using iterative lookups (i.e. so how nslookup/resolve-dnsname work anyway), and the domain I'm querying is in scope for that resolver, I should get a valid response.

Please define "failed to resolve": did you get a "No such domain" in response, or did you get an error reply from the DNS server, or nothing at all? How do the "working" and "not working" DNS queries compare in Wireshark (or some other packet capture)?

Good point... I got timeouts; specifically This operation returned because the timeout period expired. (Note: that's running the resolve-dnsname command on the same DC that hosts the conditional forwarder, so should have network connectivity... running test-netconnection from the DC to the AWS forwarder on port 53 also timedout, but connecting a [system.net.dns.udpclient] worked; implying that whilst there's no TCP listener, there is a UDP listener (there are no rules to block TCP or UDP in Azure or AWS, hence my assuming it's the lack of listener).

Sadly I can't compare the wireshark queries on the domain controllers as they're heavily locked down & running Windows Core instances, so available tooling is limitted.

I assume it's not a Windows Server version that might have pktmon, either? UDP "connections" are local-only; they bind the local socket to a recipient but don't perform any kind of network handshake (as UDP doesn't have any), so a successful connect() doesn't mean much. Not having a TCP/53 listener would be somewhat unusual for a modern DNS server, though. Can you check whether that address has a TCP/443 or TCP/853 listener? I haven't heard of Windows Server "Conditional forwarders" doing anything beyond DNS (and Do53 strongly implies regular DNS)... although DNS-over-TLS is a possibility.

Try the same query from within AWS - I wonder if the AWS DNS resolvers respond to requests from outside AWS. I haven't used it for a while, I can't recall the details. Try the query as is from within AWS, and to the .2 IP within the VPC.
